# SQL Extract Value from XML

Tags: sql, xml

I have the following XML and I want to extract the FieldValue using SQL. How can I do this?

```
  <Field Group="Annuitant">
    <FieldName>Contract Number</FieldName>
    <FieldValue>TR13116544</FieldValue>
  </Field>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<Field Group="Annuitant">
    <FieldName>Contract Number</FieldName>
    <FieldValue>TR13116544</FieldValue>
 </Field>';
```

--the lazy approach

```
SELECT @xml.value('(//FieldValue)[1]','varchar(50)')
```

--Better

```
SELECT @xml.value('(/Field/FieldValue)[1]','varchar(50)')
```

--This is, what you should do: Be as specific as possible...

```
SELECT @xml.value('(/Field/FieldValue/text())[1]','varchar(50)')
```

If there are - what I assume - are several `<Field>` elements and you need to pick the rigth one, you can do something like this:

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(100)='Contract Number';
SELECT @xml.value('(/Field[(FieldName/text())[1]=sql:variable("@name")]/FieldValue/text())[1]','varchar(50)')
```

Hint: Your question is not very clear, that needs a lot of guessing on my side. For your next question I ask you to be more specific.

Comment: Thank you very much..This is exactly what i needed.    DECLARE @name VARCHAR(100)='Contract Number';
SELECT @xml.value('(/Field[(FieldName/text())[1]=sql:variable("@name")]/FieldValue/text())[1]','varchar(50)')

Comment: OK I understand now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sample code:

```
DECLARE @MyXML XML
SET @MyXML ='<SampleXML>
<Fruits>
<Fruits1>Apple</Fruits1>
<Fruits2>Pineapple</Fruits2>
</Fruits>
</SampleXML>'

SELECT

a.b.value('Fruits[1]/Fruits1[1]','varchar(10)') AS Fruits1,
a.b.value('Fruits[1]/Fruits2[1]','varchar(10)') AS Fruits2

FROM @MyXML.nodes('SampleXML') a(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

In oracle you can do the following:

```
WITH TABL (FIELD) AS (
select xmltype('<Field Group="Annuitant">
    <FieldName>Contract Number</FieldName>
    <FieldValue>TR13116544</FieldValue>
  </Field>') from dual
) 

SELECT 
   EXTRACTVALUE(FIELD,'/Field/FieldName') AS FIELDNAME,
   EXTRACTVALUE(field,'/Field/FieldValue') AS FieldValue

FROM TABL  ;
```